# Single query to get data from two tables with different columns

Tags: mysql

I have two tables, `event` and `performer` and each of them has a `slug` column. In addition to the `slug` column, the `event` table has columns `col1`, `col2` and `col3` and the `performer` table has a column called `id`.

What I need is a single query that takes a `slug` value as input and looks at the `event` table first. If it finds a match, it returns all the columns from the `event` table. If it can't find a match, then it looks at the `performer` table and returns just the `id`.

In essence, it is the equivalent of the following two queries:

```
select col1, col2, col3 from event where slug = ?
```

If there are no results in the first query run the following:

```
select id from performer where slug = ?
```

I understand the the number of returned columns should be consistent so the value for `id` can be null in the first case and the values for `col1`, `col2` and `col3` can be null in the second case. I can test for null to see which was the case.

I would rather not have conditionals in the query - I have a feeling that it can be done with a single query, but can't figure out how.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the IF EXISTS which can all be done in one query. I know you said no conditionals, but this is an in query command.

```
IF EXISTS(select col1, col2, col3 from event where slug = ?) 
BEGIN 
select col1, col2, col3 from event where slug = ?
END
ELSE 
BEGIN
select id from performer where slug = ?
END
```

I hope this helped!

Comment: I don't want a stored procedure. I need a single query. (Remember that I am using MySQL). Thanks.